# How do I check what dependency uses the Ad ID without my knowledge

Tags: flutter, google-play

So far my app has only existed as a closed beta version for about a month now, and my latest update got removed for "Violation of Usage of Android Advertising ID policy and section 4.8 of the Developer Distribution Agreement".

Most of the results on google show the culprit for people's problems with this as '**Crashlytics**', but I'm **not using** that because I've never even heard of that before today so those threads don't help me unfortunately.

The app does not and never will show ads. My boss uses it to monitor a thermometer in his freezer. So I don't have any use for the Ad ID anyway.

I never intentionally make use of an Ad ID, so I think maybe one of my plugins do?
I don't know very well what is going on with them, and if someone could please help checking the list or telling me how to check myself, I'd appreciate it greatly.

```
dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
# The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
# Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
sqflite: any
path_provider: ^0.4.1
rxdart: ^0.18.0
charts_flutter: ^0.4.0
#image_picker: ^0.4.10
transparent_image: ^0.1.0
http: ^0.12.0
shared_preferences: ^0.5.1+1
package_info: any
```

Of all of them it might be package_info, but I'm not even really using it right now, so I can remove it completely without issue. But I'm just not sure.

If I need to show information from somewhere else please say. I'm very lost about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not easy to check which dependency uses your Ad ID, but if you want to play safe, you can add following to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file under the `<application` tag.

```
<meta-data android:name="google_analytics_adid_collection_enabled" android:value="false" />
```

Also include privacy policy in your app as well as on the play console.

Comment: I didn't add that tag, but adding a privacy policy fixed it. Having one and not needing it seems fine enough to solve the problem.